# Is description of keras backend function `gradients()` wrong?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, keras

Maybe I miss the forest for the trees, but I think the description of Keras backend function `gradients()` is wrong ([see here](https://keras.io/backend/#gradients)). 
In my opinion it should be the other way around like

`Returns the gradients of loss w.r.t. variables.`
(instead of `Returns the gradients of variables w.r.t. loss.`)

This would also match with the tensorflow description for `tf.gradients()` ([see here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients)) which is used inside Keras `gradients()`.

Do you agree?